# Speech to Text api/library

Tags: java, text, speech

What I need is an API/Library that will allow me to convert .wav files (or other media files is necessary) to their text equivalent. Does a library/api like this exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is rather typical Question. Anyhow depending on the language you are using there may be many different choices.

**Java**
http://voce.sourceforge.net/

**PHP**
http://www.speechapi.com/ and http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

Basically, the best option for you is to use some online cloud-based API, that will take your .wav input and return you the response in the text.

In this way, your API will be accessible from any language and will take a lot of pain out of your code.

Comment: Already knew of Voce just couldn't use it right but I got it now. Thanks.

Comment: That's great. If I were in your position, I would have used an online service. Just upload the file to some cloud server via code and get back the response as text.

Comment: I don't know of any cloud services, could you recommend any?

Comment: Based on a Quick search I have found a few solutions =>http://www.ispeech.org/ and http://www.voicecloud.com/voicemail-to-text-transcription/. Again if you are developing a commercial project, you might want to consider some of these. If however you are developing a personal project, you can consider other.

Comment: I am really fed up of googling something and the first link being a SO question filled with people whinging about the questioner not googling. _I_ googled, and these answers are useful!

Comment: Please have a look at link for different speech recognition softwares: 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_speech_recognition_software

Comment: the google it answer is typical also and quite pointless  : the whole mission of StackOverflow is to agreggate know how of individual who have already google and found a smarter response than the bare results of google clutered by SEO site, or previously filled with ton of pages of forum where people advise to google the questions. Then when we google that, the first resut is your answer so the question of the user was not as stupid as you pretend.

Comment: the "google it in 5 sec" is the first DONT of the code conduct of the site ! https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Answer (score 4):

If you'd have searched for *java speech recognition*, you would've found the [Java Speech API](http://jsapi.sourceforge.net/) or short *JSAPI*

Comment: I am really fed up of googling something and the first link being a SO question filled with people whinging about the questioner not googling. _I_ googled, and these answers are useful!

Comment: The whole point of StackOverflow is that, while you _could_ google, there are a lot of options, so StackOverflow lets you field curated options that people have actually tried and find a consensus of stuff that actually works. /metadiscussion

Comment: the "google it in 5 sec" is the first DONT of the code conduct of the site ! https://stackoverflow.com/conduct